# SocketTimeOutException in Chrome ARC app

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I am getting java.net.SocketTimeOutException (Read timed out) for some of our Apis in ARC app. It started happening since last few days. Everything was working fine earlier. I have correctly set the ConnectTimeout and ReadTimeout values in the HttpsURLConnection. What we observed is that the server is sending the response on time but the client (ARC app) is not receiving the response and ending up with TimeOut exception. This happens with some Apis but not all.

Note: We have no issue on Android. This is the problem with ARC app.

Is there any change in the ARC runtime which is causing it?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the ARC runtime. I installed the ARC app on my Macbook and caused the same problem. So I think some ARC runtime update is causing it.

Comment: Have found the issue. This is happening due to PlayServices. After removing "usePlayServices" from the manifest, it started working. Reported this to Google.